# Importing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word breaks New Frame()

Tags: wpf, vb.net

The problem is importing **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word** (which I need elsewhere in this class) breaks "New Frame()". The error is

> 'New' cannot be used on an interface

My guess is that Interop.Word redefines "frame". How do I fix this?

My code:

```
Imports C1.WPF
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

End Sub

Private Sub btn_SendQuote_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn_SendQuote.Click

    Dim tab_SendQuote As New C1TabItem()
    Dim frame_SendQuote As New Frame()
    Dim scroller_SendQuote As New ScrollViewer()
    Dim str_Name As String = "Send Quote"
    Dim str_NavigationLink As String = "PM_SendQuote.xaml"

    createNewTab(tab_SendQuote, frame_SendQuote, scroller_SendQuote, str_Name, str_NavigationLink)
End Sub

Private Sub createNewTab(tab As C1TabItem, frame As Frame, scroller As ScrollViewer, str_TabName As String, str_NavigationLink As String)
    'Function to be used for adding tabs

    'Add and name new tab
    tab.Header = tabcontrol.Items.Count + 1 & ". " & str_TabName
    tab.CanUserClose = True
    tabcontrol.Items.Add(tab)

    'Add frame to the tab and include new job subform page
    With frame
        .NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(str_NavigationLink, UriKind.Relative))
        .HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
        .VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
        .Margin = New Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)
    End With

    With scroller
        .CanContentScroll = vbTrue
        .VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
        .HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
        .Content = frame
    End With

    tab.Content = scroller
    ' Set new tab as active tab
    tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = tabcontrol.Items.IndexOf(tab)

End Sub
```

Comment: Im not sure why but using 'Imports Word Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word' fixes the error.

Comment: Thats strange... would be a different story for the alias declaration `Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` but without the `=` it should give you some errors and with the `=` you would need to qualify all word types with the alias...